# How could this molecule affect the body? (Lysergic acid derivative)

Tags: molecular-biology, pharmacology, pharmacokinetics, pharmacodynamics, bioinorganic-chemistry

[image]

First of all, could you please help me name this molecule? I think the name of it is something like this: *N,N-pentamethylene lysergic acid*. Secondly, **my main question is** what could be the pharmacology / mechanism of action (eg the target receptors, etc.) of this molecule? I couldn't find any info on [DrugBank](https://www.drugbank.ca/), so I'm all ears to your ideas. Please help me on this; it is quite a burning question.

P.S.: If there are any mistakes in my English, please excuse me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is [lysergic acid piperidide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSD-Pip), an analog of [lysergic acid diethylamide (LSD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysergic_acid_diethylamide). According to Wikipedia, it is an agonist of the [5-HT<sub>2A</sub>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5-HT2A_receptor) receptor, but is much less potent than LSD.

Comment: @ostal123 You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answer if it has, in fact, answered your question.